# C# SaveAs to CSV Display Long Text as # Instead of Value

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

MS Excel turn text cell into ### when it is long, but it still have value when I click on it. But when the file is converted to CSV, the value is gone and only the ### is saved.

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

workBook.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
   workBook.SaveAs(
      "foo.csv",
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV
   );
workBook.Close(true);
excel.Quit();
```

The expected output for the text cell should be a text, but it save as ### instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce the described behavior. 1. I don't get #### with text, only with numbers that don't have enough space in the column width. 2. When I use the code in the question it saves to a csv file; when that is opened in a text editor I see the complete number, no hash marks. What are you doing differently?

Answer (score -1):

You could try saving it as a csv file without making it a workbook?
this has a good example on how to do so.
https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/write-data-into-csv-file-in-c

Comment: Please take a moment to review the site guidelines in the [help]. All information necessary for solving the question needs to be *in the answer* and not rely on a link to another site. Stack Overflow's concept is to maintain a long-term Q&A. Over time, links can become invalid, so it's important that the relevant information is stored here. You can copy/paste the relevant information if you can't create your own example, as long as you give adequate attribution.